# Apache Kafka consumer cannot deserialize java POJO

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am having problems to configure my kafka consumer to de-serialize Java objects that I send as payload by my producer. I will get the following error message:

> cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to [foo.bar.MyObject] for GenericMessage [payload={"type":"doc","content":"A"}, (..)]

My object just contains two fields:

```java
@Data
public class MyObject {
    String type;
    String content;
}
```

I have added a JSON serializer for my object to my kafka configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class KafkaConf {

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        JsonDeserializer myJsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(MyObject.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, myJsonDeserializer);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, MyObject> myObjectConsumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

}
```

I am also explicitly specifying my consumer factory in the kafka listener like this:

```java
    @KafkaListener(topics = "doc", groupId = "repliesGroup", containerFactory = "myObjectConsumerFactory")
    @SendTo
    public List<String> listen(MyObject foo) {
        return myService.doStuff(foo);
    }
```

What am I still missing here?

Comment: What is `qlfJsonDeserializer` from `props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, qlfJsonDeserializer);`?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko my bad, should be moJsonDeserializer, I swapped some class name to generalize the question. I will make an edit.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the type mappings - https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#serdes-mapping-types

Answer (score 0):

I was running the same problem, it was fixed after setting the containerFactory (you already have this) and adding the deserializers by class name:

```
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class.getName());
```

Also added the default type for the consumer:

```
properties.put(JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE,"foo.bar.MyObject");
```

Also my @KafkaLister method annotates the @Payload parameter.